# Swap letters between words

Tags: wordplay

Start with these three words in order: MULE PITS RANK. The goal is to swap letters that have an identical place in the word, while still keeping the resulting strings as words, and eventually get PITS MULE RANK. What is the smallest number of swaps that can be used to do this?

Comment: The answer is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total: 4 swaps

MULE PITS RANK

> MILE PUTS RANK

> PILE MUTS RANK

> PILS MUTE RANK

PITS MULE RANK

Comment: Of the six words you form, one is not in the Oxford English Dictionary and another is in but only as a proper noun.